# Rendering multiple components for a single route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an application that uses a three column layout with basically a navigation column, a toolbox and a main content area. Not all of these components are not necessarily always present. I would now like to render a different component in each of these columns.

For the moment, I am doing this by hard-coding the components from left to right: The navigation column is always present, next to it is an `router-outlet`. Inside that router the editor is loaded and the provided sidebar is hardcoded. This is ugly for two reasons:

- I would like to allow the user to re-order these columns. But this is difficult due to the "incorrect" parent-child relationship. It would be far easier if all columns were siblings.
- Apart from that the navigation column is an utter mess consisting of loads of switch-case statements to display the correct kind of navigation depending on the current route.

What I am looking for instead is something like this:

```
<router-outlet name="navigation"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

At first I thought auxiliary routes are the thing I was looking for. But after doing some reading it seems that these routes introduce a completely separate sub-tree in the navigation URL? I want to render these components based on exactly the same URL.

I could of course do my own "sort of" routing by introducing a meta-sidebar full of switch statements just like I have effectively done with the navigation. But this does a) break lazy loading and is b) not very pleasant to work with.

In case I have been to abstract so far, this is the quite exact use case: The main content area is some kind of editor for SQL, CSS or HTML. Depending on what exactly is edited, the navigation column displays data down to a certain level. The other column is more or less a context sensitive toolbox, which displays different items depending on the type of the edited content. All three components require exactly the same information from the URL: What is the thing that is currently edited?

[image: Three column layout with nav column, editor and sidebar]

Comment: Maybe use a custom router-outlet that reads route-data to decide how to update the nav section.   Here's an example of a custom outlet that enforces log-in: https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that extending the router was so relatively easy. I will read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple router outlet, However they can not be activated with one URL, because when you configure Route config , the path has to be uniquely identified.

You might have to write your custom logic to read the URL `params` and based upon that invoke some embedded child routes, which will fetch different components for your different areas.

Comment: What do you mean by "invoking some embedded child routes"?